# Can Shopp Commercial Plugin be hacked to display radio buttons instead of Dropdowns?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, e-commerce, plugin-shopp

I need to know if the 'Shopp' e-commerce plugin can be modified to display radio buttons instead of drop down menus for the product options. I don't need you to tell me how this can be done (though that would certainly be welcome), just if it is possible. I don't want to invest in Shopp unless it is something that has been done before and there is a thread or article on the Shopp board that explains the hack.

EDIT: Seriously, I just need someone w/ access to the Shopp user forums to login and run a quick search for that kind of mod.

Comment: Shopop has a pre purchase forum where you can ask this question

Comment: Nope, they don't but thanks for going out of your way to vote that down. They have a pre-purchase support contact, however after contacting them, I was informed that they couldn't comment on hacks and mods to the plugin.

Comment: http://forums.shopplugin.net/ I would have thought they would have answered the question. Did you ask whether it was possible, or did you ask how it could be done? If you asked the how question, of course they would't answer as that would defeat the purpose of paid support.

Comment: forums.shopplugin.net is not accessible by people who have yet to purchase the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example highlights the versatility of interface options you can create by using radio inputs to select a product variation rather than the default  menus.

This section of code could be used in place of the variations code block in either the product.php template file or the category.php template file (if you want variation inputs in your category products list).

```
<?php if(shopp('product','has-variations')): ?>
<ul class="variations">
    <?php while(shopp('product','variations')): ?>
        <li>
            <label>
            <input type="radio" name="products[<?php shopp('product','id'); ?>][price]" value="<?php shopp('product','variation','id'); ?>" />
            <?php shopp('product','variation','label'); ?>
            </label>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Warning**
Using this will make it able to add empty products to your cart (if the product has variations)

Comment: It worked flawlessly. It helped me make a quick change for a customer. Thanks Roswell :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I reply to Roswell. I've updated his loop to help with empty variations

```
<?php if(shopp('product','has-variations')): ?>
<ul class="variations">
    <?php while(shopp('product','variations')): ?>
        <li>
            <?php if( shopp('product','variation','stock&return=1') > 0 ) : ?>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="products[<?php shopp('product','id'); ?>][price]" value="<?php shopp('product','variation','id'); ?>" />
                    <?php shopp('product','variation','label'); ?>
                </label>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can submit an edit to his post using the 'edit' link below his post.

Comment: @bungeshea & Dean, editing someone else's code depends on some factors, for clarifications if it applies in this case please check: [How far can I refactor someone else's code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88627/185667).

Comment: @brasofilo Perhaps this better in a separate answer, after all (it couldn't really fit in a comment).